# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Login timeout expired on WSL 2

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyodbc

**first**, I should say to you that I use ubuntu on wsl2 in a windows 10, **then** I installed sql server on windows 10.
then used blow commands to install pyodb:
`sudo apt install python3-pyodbc`

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version




#Ubuntu 20.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list



exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

**after**,  I create `tesrt.py` and put the following code on it:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                        'SERVER=HQ-PC-059\KAISQL;'
                        'USER=sa;'
                        'PASSWORD=pass;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

I ran this app, **at the end** I gave this error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I don't have any idea but I connected to that with sqlcmd:
`Sqlcmd -S HQ-PC-059\KAISQL -U sa -P pass`
thank you <3

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=yes` is wrong if you are using the `sa` login. Can you connect with `sqlcmd` from the same machine?

Comment: Remove `Trusted_Connection=yes` from your connection string. Use either SQL Login authentication (Username and Password, or UID and PWD, depending on the driver) _or_ Windows/Kerberos (Trusted_Connection), but don't try to mix the two.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport

Comment: @Charlieface

I removed it but issue is established.

Comment: As per [Connecting from Linux or macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns) have you tried `UID` and `PWD` keywords instead of `USER` and `PASSWORD`?